# Rotate Display at Startup

Tags: startup, games

So I'm trying to rotate the screen upside down at startup because the screen I'm working must be upside down. I'm working with a game emulation OS called Lakka, so I can't use "xrandr" to flip it. 
So far I've done the following:

```
"mount -o remount,rw /flash"
-"nano /flash/extlinux.conf"
-I then added "fbcon=rotate:2" to the end of the line
-"mount -o remount,ro /flash"
-then rebooted the system
```

Yet there's still no rotation of the menu. Any ideas? Am I missing something? (please be easy on me, I'm a bit of a noobie :) )